# drag object using mouse Listener

Tags: java, user-interface, mouseevent, mouselistener

I'm trying to create a program that able the user to drag and drop the oval around in the space. I was able to drag and drop but after I tried do it again on the second run, the oval jump all over the places. I was wondering if anyone know why this happen? Am i missing something? Thank you

```
public class MoveOval extends JFrame {

private Ellipse2D node = new Ellipse2D.Float(200,200,80,120);
private Point offset;
private int preX,preY;
private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;
Adapter ma = new Adapter();

public static void main(String args[]){
    JFrame frame = new MoveOval();
    frame.setSize(600,600); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public MoveOval(){
    super("Move Oval");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addMouseListener(ma);
    addMouseMotionListener(ma);

}
private class Adapter extends MouseAdapter{
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        if(node.contains(e.getPoint())){
            preX = node.getBounds().x-e.getX();
            preY = node.getBounds().y-e.getX();
            offset = new Point(preX, preY);
        }
    }
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
        if(node.contains(e.getPoint())){
            updateLocation(e);
        }
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
           offset=null;
      }

}

public void updateLocation(MouseEvent e){
    Point to = e.getPoint();
    to.x += offset.x;
    to.y += offset.y;

    Rectangle bounds = node.getBounds();
    bounds.setLocation(to);
    node.setFrame(bounds);

    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    dbImage=createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D gd = (Graphics2D)g.create();
    gd.setColor(Color.blue);
    gd.fill(node);

    }
}
```

Comment: Much better if you were to create and post a valid [mcve] (please check out the link for the important details). Also you should never draw directly within a JFrame's paint method as that's asking for trouble, especially as you're breaking the painting chain by not calling any super method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually a very simple mistake and easy to fix.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        if(node.contains(e.getPoint())){
            preX = node.getBounds().x-e.getX();
            preY = node.getBounds().y-e.getX(); // <- That's the bad guy.
            offset = new Point(preX, preY);
        }
    }
```

It has to be -e.getY() not -e.getX().

Comment: Thank YOU!! i can't believe i didn't see that. :)

Comment: This kind of thing occasionally happens to me, too, when I get really tired. Sometimes it's the simple mistakes you miss. Anyway I would appreciate if you marked this as the right answer.